# Unity - InputSystem error : "Cannot generate reader for abstract class InputControl"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I have been using the new Unity Input System with good success until I got this error and I don't know how to solve it.
The first error reads "(0,0): error Cannot generate writer for abstract class InputControl". [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhqEF.png)

I am using Input System 1.3.0. I also use the networking asset Mirror in case it has something to do with it.

Can someone help me here ? =)

Comment: Questions about debugging on stack overflow should include a [mre]. See [ask] for more information. [Searching for "cannot generate reader for abstract class"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cannot+generate+writer+for+abstract+class%22) results in Mirror code, so I'm pretty sure it is a Mirror error. Are you perhaps asking Mirror to try to do something with these classes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes I figured later that it is a Mirror error but related to its weaver trying to serialize one of the Input System class.

The problem is that I can't really "reproduce" this error. I got it in the console after launching Unity last time and there are no errors in my code for Visual Studio. Rebooting everything doesn't change anything, I just have this error in the editor's console.

The error goes away if I remove all the lines related to the use of the new Input System though.

Comment: If you attached the `[Command]` annotation to an Input Handler method to cause this error, that should be included in the question as well to help others reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem :

I added the [Command] header over one of my Input Handler method, after removing it it works fine.

```
    //[Command]
public void OnScroll(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
```

not

```
    [Command]
public void OnScroll(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
```